# VBA need Range assistance

Tags: vba, ms-word

the following is the function I have for adding the non underlined entry

(to simplify it a bit, there is also a function that does this twice adding 1 string underlined and then the string after it not underlined)

```
Function Add_Single_Entry(ByVal uEntry As String, ByVal ptime As String, ByVal crntValue As String)

    uEntry = UCase( uEntry )
    Call add_tList( ptime )
    Dim rng1 As Word.Range

    ' Set Selection position however is appropriate
    Set rng1 = Selection.Range
    rng1.End = rng1.Start
    rng1.Text = uEntry
    Selection.Start = rng1.End
End Function
```

I need to be able to set my starting point to be the next line after the last instance of `crntValue` but I'm not sure how.

to clarify i would like the code to find the last instance of say "`0000Z`" (`crntValue`) in a Word document and then input a string on the next line.

Comment: Please provide more context. What is an "entry" in this case? What is your function meant to do as far as the Word user is concerned?

Comment: an "Entry" is a String compiled from various user inputed information and pre-set variables, the point is that the program has alot of buttons which when clicked ask for some information and then add a string to the word document with a time stamp -crntValue- which usually looks like "0000Z" i need the program to find the last instance of crntValue that is in the word document and then add an "Entry" after it.

Comment: Also @Dai thank you for the edit still figuring this forum out, ive never really used these kinds of things before.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, the macro recorder is a good help - just record "goto end, find upwards, insert new line" and adapt the recorded code.

Something like

```
' goto end of document
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
With Selection.Find
    .Text = crntValue
    .Forward = False    ' from bottom to top
    .Format = False
    ' adapt to your needs
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
End With
' Check if the string was found
If Selection.Find.Execute() Then
    ' goto end of line
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    ' and insert new line
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    ' now you're ready to insert your entry
Else
    MsgBox "Sorry, " & crntValue & " was not found.", vbExclamation
End If
```

Comment: did this code work correctly for you, i only played around with it for a minute when i saw it but so far all it has done is added a newline to the bottom of my word document ....

Comment: Added a check whether the string was found, see edit. But yes, if the string is in the document, it worked for me. Note: this code goes into your existing function at `' Set Selection position however is appropriate`, it doesn't replace it.

Comment: ok the check helped me to realize that even though the crntValue is pulled from a list only stored from previous entries, its not finding it in the document, but i can see it in the document infront of me. I will continue to play around as to why this may happen but wanted to update you incase you could decipher this issue quicker, thank you for all your help as well

Comment: Use "Advanced Find" in Word to search for the string manually. It's in the Search dropdown in the ribbon. Actually I don't know which Word version you are using, but I assume 2010 +/- 1. There you can set the search direction. If you do a successful find, record it, and compare the recorded VBA code with the one you have now.

Comment: yes i am able to ctrl+f search up from bottom and find the string but everytime i run the code the msg says cannot find ... perhaps im setting the range incorrectly for the code to search through

Comment: You're the best, i figured it out, for some reason it needed .matchwildcards but it works perfectly now thank you soooo much